# Fetching google images using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I would like to execute a query on google images to fetch images using htmlagilitypack in c#.
For this I used an xpath request to the image

```
//*[@id="rg_s"]/div[1]/a/img
```

But it fails to fetch the image that way. What could be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Searching google programmatically outside of their API's is against the [TOS](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/#toc-services).  Consider [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) or [Bing Search API](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search), both of which have established JSON and SOAP interfaces.

Both are free for a couple thousand queries per month and comply with the service's TOS.

Edit: Examples of using Bing API with C# below:

```
const string bingKey = "[your key here]";
var bing = new BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/")) 
{ 
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(bingKey, bingKey) 
};

var query = bing.Web("Jon Gallant blog", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
var results = query.Execute();

foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Url);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Google custom search API:

```
string apiKey = "Your api key";
string cx = "Your custom search engine id";
string query = "Your query";

var svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });
var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);

listRequest.Cx = cx;
var search = listRequest.Fetch();

foreach (var result in search.Items)
{
    Response.Output.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result.Title);
    Response.Output.WriteLine("Link: {0}", result.Link);
}
```

Comment: can i use the apis with c#

Comment: @aceBox, yes.  Both are HTTP API's which can be accessed directly or using the clients provided.  Both sign-up pages have examples and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this too : Here its possible to get the links of images by following

```
var links = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").Where(a => a.InnerHtml.Contains("<img")).Select(b => b.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
 foreach(var link in links)
  {
      // you can save the link or do your process here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google keeps found images in `div` tags with class `rg_di`. Here is a query to get all links to images:

```
var links = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='rg_di']/a")
                .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
```

Comment: It gives an error : "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection" doesn't contain a definition for select

Comment: @aceBox just add `using System.Linq` directive. `Select` is an extension method for enumerable types

Comment: Actually, now what i am doing is var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath); and then nodes[i].GetAttributeValue("href",""). Is your method same to this?

Comment: @aceBox yes, my method does same thing, but in more simple way - it projects nodes collection into urls collection with LINQ